# CodeIgniter 3.1.9 Form Validation

Tags: codeigniter, validation, validationrules, reserved

I have a problem with a form validation in CI.
The rule seems does not call the function
My code is the following:

```
[...]    
$this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'last name','trim|required|min_length[3]|max_length[30]|callback_reserved',
    [
        'required'      => 'The %s is missed',
        'min_length'    => 'The %s must contain at least %s letters',
        'max_length'    => 'The %s must contain at max %s letters',
    ]);
[...]

function reserved($str) {
    $reserved = ['aaaa','bbbb','cccc','dddd'];
    if (in_array(strtolower($str), $reserved)) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('reserved', 'The {field} '.$str.' is reserved');
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi & welcome to StackOverflow ! Please share your actual issue, not only a piece of code. It’s quite unclear of what you are asking :/ you may want to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get pro tips :)

Comment: I've answered your question with a better non complicated way of creating a custom validation rule cause using call back is a bit complicated and you got to create the rule in your controller not your model and so on .. so if you prefer this way i can explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a better way to create a custom validation rule:

```
$config = array(
    'field'     => 'last_name',
    'label'     => 'last name',
    'rules'     => array('trim', 'required', array('last_name_is_reserved',
        function($str)
        {
            $reserved = ['aaaa','bbbb','cccc','dddd'];
            return (in_array(strtolower($str), $reserved)) ? TRUE : FALSE;
        }),
    ),
    'errors' => array(
        'last_name_is_reserved' => 'The {field} field is reserved.',
    ),
);
$this->form_validation->set_rules($config);
```